# Flask returning random template for 404 errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, error-handling

Flask keeps returning a weird 404 default template and ignores my custom made template. I have no idea why.

Here is my **init**

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    #Fixes flask db upgrade to allow deleting columns
    with app.app_context():
        if db.engine.url.drivername == 'sqlite':
            migrate.init_app(app, db, render_as_batch=True)
        else:
            migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login.init_app(app)
    babel.init_app(app)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Bob startup')
    app.redis = Redis.from_url(app.config['REDIS_URL'])
    app.task_queue = rq.Queue('offutt-tasks', connection=app.redis)

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    return app

from app import models
```

Here is my **init** in my errors folder:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('errors', __name__)

from app.errors import handlers
```

Finally here is my handlers page with the routes.

```
from flask import render_template, request
from app import db
from app.errors import bp
#from app.api.errors import error_response as api_error_response

def wants_json_response():
    return request.accept_mimetypes['application/json'] >= \
        request.accept_mimetypes['text/html']

@bp.errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error(error):
    #if wants_json_response():
    #    return api_error_response(404)
    return render_template('errors/404.html'), 404


@bp.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    db.session.rollback()
    #if wants_json_response():
    #    return api_error_response(500)
    return render_template('errors/500.html'), 500
```

my 404.html renders fine when i write a route to go directly to it, but the errorhandler does not seem to be working at all. All it renders is a page saying "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use `@app.errorhandler(404)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `app_errorhandler()` to use it for all requests, even outside of the blueprint [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler). E.g.

```
@bp.app_errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error(error):
    ....
```